# How to check the current value of IFS?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am currently running a shell script and I suspect the problem may be because I accidentally changed the default value of [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) which is a space  to something else.

I want to check the current value of IFS, but I don't know how to go about finding it .

I am running my Ubuntu on VMWare.

Answer (score 23):

```
> printf %q "$IFS"
' \t\n'
```

The `%q` format argument is used to interpolate the quoted variable `$IFS` and escapes control characters that would be interpreted by the shell.

Here you can see that IFS separates on spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Answer (score 14):

As you probably already know, the default value of `IFS` is `<space><tab><newline>`. Using:

```
echo "$IFS"
```

you can probably deduce that there is a newline character and some other white space characters, but nothing sure.

To be sure about the exact value of the`IFS` variable, you can appeal to the help of `cat` command as follow:

```
echo "$IFS" | cat -ETv
```

which is equivalent with:

```
cat -ETv <<< "$IFS"
```

Sample output for the default value of `IFS`:

```
cat -ETv <<< "$IFS"
 ^I$
$
```

From the previous output you can deduce that there sure is one space character at the beginning and a newline character. But what is with the others strange characters. Let's look at the `man cat`:

> ```
>    -E, --show-ends
>           display $ at end of each line
>
>    -T, --show-tabs
>           display TAB characters as ^I
>
>    -v, --show-nonprinting
>           use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD (n.a. linefeed or newline character) and TAB
> ```

So, the `^I` sequence from the above output means one TAB character and the other two `$` characters means the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
0000000  sp  ht  nl
        040 011 012
             \t  \n
0000003
```

http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Show_IFS_value

Comment: Why the down vote? This answer conveys precisely the content of IFS in 3 different notations.

Comment: It would be nice with a short explanation of the `od` command and the options you suggest. I imagine the down vote may have been related to [how-to-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The command `echo $IFS` (note the absence of double quotes) may not show the value of IFS correctly because of [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

For example:

```
IFS=:
echo $IFS  # shows a blank line
```

So, the right way to display IFS is:

```
echo "$IFS"
```

Other ways are:

```
set | grep -w IFS # shows IFS=$' \t\n'
printf '[%s]\n' "$IFS"
```

---

Related:

- [Word splitting in Bash with IFS set to a non-whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43163225/6862601)
- [Word Splitting - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: The echo and printf ones aren't super great with newlines... (just show blank lines)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but another answer, and easy one that I have not seen posted yet is the following command

```
echo "${IFS@Q}" # which will result in the following (defaults)
' \t\n'
```

If you simply use

```
echo "$IFS" #Your result will be this
```

...an empty line showing the invisible characters which isnt much help.

Hope this helps
Aloha