# Unable to set/reset IFS

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ifs

I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 (**Edit: Now updated to 16.04.7**), with bash 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
I am not able to set/reset my IFS variable. I have tried to set is using the literal CTRL+V  and  as well. Even tried `unset`.

Interestingly, the behaviour the same for any other variable (`$Other_IFS` below).

Any pointers?

Below is the output of my attempts:

```
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ IFS=$' \t\n'
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ IFS="   ^M"
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ unset IFS 
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ IFS="   ^M"
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ Other_IFS="   ^M"
mike@laptop:~ $ IFS="$Other_IFS"
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $IFS 
$
mike@laptop:~ $ cat -vte <<< $Other_IFS 
$
```

**Edit:** (*based on some of the comments, I am adding an example*):

The data file: (TAB separated)

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
312      19     [1,1,3,2]
763       1     [2,3,0,8]
 12     104     [3,0,0,3]
150     208     [3,0,2,3]
```

I am sorting the file on `Col1` and getting the values of `Col2` and `Col3` of the last entry (after sorting), in an array. Then I am printing the array values separately. Here is the command used to achieve this:

```
max=($(sort -t $'\t' -n -k1,1 my_file | cut -d $'\t' -f2,3 | tail -1))
echo ${max[1]}
```

In the above example, the output is

```
[2,
```

instead of `[2,3,0,8]`.

At the beginning of the script, I have already added

```
OFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\t'
```

and at the end,

```
IFS="$OFS"
```

---

**Note**
On a different system (`Ubuntu 20.04.1, bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`), the script is producing an expected output.

Comment: FYI:  Your system is behind on upgraded packages, if you're online I suggest updating your system for security purposes. An updated system should report itself as 16.04.7 http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/

Comment: I think your setting IFS works well, but your printing not. What about `printf "%q" "$IFS"` ?

Comment: @guiverc, Yes, I have now upgraded and now its 16.0.7. However, the problem is still the same.

Comment: @pLumo, the `printf` command gives the following: `$' \t\n'`. But my scripts are not working (which are working well on the other systems).

Comment: So, it is how it should be. I would say, you should post a new question with your script and the problem you have with that. This question can then be closed as duplicate of [How to check the current value of IFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437182/how-to-check-the-current-value-of-ifs).

Comment: you never quote your `$IFS`  --> `cat -vte <<< "$IFS"`